# JAVA - what is the difference between void and boolean methods?

Tags: java, methods, boolean, void

I am completely new to JAVA. I am writing a wrapper-library in JAVA to make some functions available in Basic-like language.

I got stock at a certain point when I noted that some code were not executed in the JAVA-library although the compiler did not complain (using Eclipse). I resolved it finally by replacing the code as follows:

```
public void VideoQuality(int vQuality) //did not work
```

into

```
public boolean VideoQuality(int vQuality) //works
```

Here are the complete code-snippets:

```
 public void VideoQuality(int vQuality) //did not work
        {if (vQuality==16) {
            vidQuality=16;
            }
            else if (vQuality==-16)  {
                vidQuality=-16;
            }
            else if (vQuality==0)  {
                vidQuality=0;
            }
            else
                vidQuality=-16;
        vitamioExt.setVideoQuality(vidQuality);
         }  

public boolean VideoQuality(int vQuality) //works
        {if (vQuality==16) {
            vidQuality=16;
            }
            else if (vQuality==-16)  {
                vidQuality=-16;
            }
            else if (vQuality==0)  {
                vidQuality=0;
            }
            else
                vidQuality=-16;
        vitamioExt.setVideoQuality(vidQuality);
        return true;
          }
```

I think **void** corresponds to a sub in Visual Basic while **boolean** corresponds to a function.

I found it odd however that the following code worked using **void**

```
public void setVolume(float leftVolume,float rightVolume)
      {
          vitamioExt.setVolume(leftVolume, rightVolume);
      }
```

I am surely missing something very obvious but I can't see why the **void**-code would not work while the **boolean**-code worked.

Maybe it depends how I call the code?

Anyone who can shed some lights?

EDIT: to clarify what was not working, I meant that the code:

```
vitamioExt.setVideoQuality(vidQuality);
```

did not execute in the void-snippet.

EDIT2: vidQuality was declared in a different part of the code. I just posted the snippets since the problems were with those and variables were all functioning.

EDIT3: At the end, I guess I must have called the void-snippet erroneously although the compiler did not compile. In either case, both snippets should execute although of course the void-snippet would be the right one to use since I did not expect a return-value.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to define two methods with the same signature and different return types in Java. The compiler should have failed in that line, provided that both methods are defined in the same class. This is not evident in your code.

Comment: @moster67, it would be good for you to read an introductory Java book or tutorial first, perhaps the official Java Tutorial which should be available for download from Oracle. People can answer this question for you, but if you haven't learned basics like this, you will find it hard to make anything work in Java. It would be more efficient to just read the tutorial first before you start programming.

Comment: -1 because "did not work" is "not sufficient".

Comment: What is a void? Nothing...therefore returning void means there is no return for the method. If its a boolean, a boolean value is returned from that function.

Comment: Explain "did not work." What happened? What did you expect to happen? Why do you think it should have been the way you thought, rather than the way it was?

Comment: The difference between a void method and a boolean method is that a boolean method returns a boolean result to the caller, while a void method does not return a value.  That is all.

Comment: Not really relevant, but I believe it would be better to use a *switch* statement here, rather than if elif and else blocks.

Comment: Both should have worked, however method names should be lower case by convention.  Nothing is implied by the void keyword.  All that it says is that you are not returning anything from the function.

Comment: Correction: neither should work because you dont even declare vidQuality.

Comment: LOL - I agree that I need to read a JAVA-book and that down-points are well-earned. As I said, I got the wrapper working at the end using boolean and the line "vitamioExt.setVideoQuality(vidQuality);" got executed. However, while using the void-version, that line did not get executed. However, the Public void SetVolume worked and it seems similar to the void-code that did not work.That is why I am confused.

Comment: @LINEMAN78: `vidQuality` could be an instance member.

Comment: @LINEMAN78: vidQuality was declared and set in the code as follows: "private int vidQuality=16;". I just wanted to post the snippets which caused me problems.

Comment: What did not work ? what was the error resulted ? Folks here wouldnt be able to help if there is not much info in the question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only difference between

```
public void VideoQuality(int vQuality)
```

and

```
public boolean VideoQuality(int vQuality)
```

is that the former doesn't return a value, and the latter does (specifically, a `boolean` value). That's the full extent of the difference.

That means, for instance, that with the `void` version of `VideoQuality`:

```
boolean x = VideoQuality(10); // Will not compile
VideoQuality(10);             // Will compile
```

...because you can't assign the result of a `void` function to a variable.

If you used the `boolean` version of `VideoQuality`:

```
boolean x = VideoQuality(10); // Will compile
VideoQuality(10);             // Will compile
```

...because although you *can* assign the result of a function that returns `boolean` to a `boolean` variable, you don't *have* to. You can ignore the return value if you like. (Usually that's not good practice, but sometimes it's okay.)

> I think void corresponds to a sub in Visual Basic while boolean corresponds to a function.

Loosely speaking, yes. `void` indicates that the function has no return value, like `Sub` in VB. Anything else (`boolean`, `int`, `Foo`, whatever) indicates that A) The function has a return value, and B) It is of the given type. So that's like `Function` in VB.

Comment: good explanation. After all, it is basic for most programming languages. I guess I must somehow called the void-snippet wrongly although it seems odd because the compiler should have complained if I  used a wrong syntax. Anyway thanks!

Comment: @monster if you feel this answered your question, and solved your problem, you're encouraged to 'accept' it as your answer.

Comment: @corsiKa: moster67 if I may - not monster! Just kidding. I know very well that I should accept an answer. I still have't made my mind up yet. I left some comments and maybe there were will be further comments? However, please be sure that I will accept one of the replies I got.

Answer (score 1):

Functions are declared with a type, much like regular variables, but a function's declared type is called its **return type**, which says "this function will return as a boolean when called." For example:

```
boolean alive = true;
boolean isDogAlive() {
    return alive;
}
```

If this function is called, it will return true, so you could say

```
if (! isDogAlive()) { // if it returns false
    System.out.println("Oh no!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Yay!");
}
```

Functions are declared ***void*** if they don't return anything. You shouldn't need to give a method a boolean return type unless you actually need to get the true/false value. Void should work fine for your situation.

Comment: OK, so looking at the code-snippets I provided, both should actually work and execute the line "vitamioExt.setVideoQuality(vidQuality);". Of course, in this case the void-method is the one I should use since I am not interested in a return-value like happens in the boolean(function)-code. I guess as this point, I must have called the void-version erroneously and that's why it never executed.